# How to ignore a particular scenario in a feature file in karate at runtime?

Tags: karate

@tag is per feature file , But Is there a way we can ignore a particular scenario in a feature file while running tests ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a tag above your scenario and set it to ignore that tag while running

```
@ignore
Scenario:
    * print "ignored test"

@regression
Scenario:
    * print "regression test"
```

now if you want to ignore **@ignore**  tag then you can use a '~' symbol before tags which you don't want to run in your cucumber options

eg:

i) passing as arguments

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@ignore" -Dtest=YourTestClass
```

or

ii) Defining in your test class itself

```
@CucumberOptions( tags = {"~@ignore"})
```

or

iii) for karate standalone pass additional argument with **-t** flag

```
-t ~@ignore
```

Comment: No your java class which you will call to invoke your feature